# For a classification model in tensorflow, is there a way to impose an asymmetric cost function during the training?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a Neural Network in tensorflow where the cost of a Type I error (false-positive) is more costly than a Type II error (false-negative). Is there a way to impose this during the training process (i.e. inputting a cost matrix)? This is possible with simple models like Logistic Regression in scikit learn by specifying the class_weight parameter.

```
cw = {0: 3,1:1}
clf = LogisticRegression(class_weight = cw )
```

In this case, incorrectly predicting a 0 is 3x more costly than incorrectly predicting a 1. However, this cannot be performed with a Neural Network, so I want to see if it is possible in tensorflow.

Thanks

Comment: Specify a custom loss function?

Comment: yes, exactly what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits) and it's `pos_weight` argument.

This argument weights **positive class**, as described by documentation (in TF2.0 at least):

```
A value pos_weights > 1 decreases the false negative count, hence increasing the recall. 
Conversely setting pos_weights < 1 decreases the false positive count and increases the precision.
```

In your case, you could create custom loss function like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf


# Output logits from your network, not the values after sigmoid activation
class WeightedBinaryCrossEntropy:
    def __init__(self, positive_weight: float):
        self.positive_weight = positive_weight

    def __call__(self, targets, logits, sample_weight=None):
        return tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            targets, logits, pos_weight=self.positive_weight
        )
```

And create a custom neural network with it, for example using `tf.keras` (samples are weighted as they were in your question:

```
import numpy as np


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, input_shape=(10,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
        tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu"),
        # Output one logit for binary classification
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    ]
)

# Example random data
data = np.random.random((32, 10))
targets = np.random.randint(2, size=32)

# 3 times as costly to make type I error
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=WeightedBinaryCrossEntropy(positive_weight=3))
model.fit(data, targets, batch_size=32)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a logarithmic scale. For a 0 incorrectly predicted as 1, `y - ŷ = -1`, log goes to 1.71. For a 1 predicted as 0, `y - ŷ = 1` log equals 0.63. For `y == ŷ` log equals 0. Almost the three times more costly, for a 0 incorrectly predicted as 1.

```
import numpy as np
from math import exp

loss=abs(1-exp(-np.log(exp(y-ŷ))))


#abs(1-exp(-np.log(exp(0))))
#Out[53]: 0.0

#abs(1-exp(-np.log(exp(-1))))
#Out[54]: 1.718281828459045

#abs(1-exp(-np.log(exp(1))))
#Out[55]: 0.6321205588285577
```

Then you will have a convex optimization. Implementing:

```
import keras.backend as K

def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    return K.mean(abs(1-exp(-np.log(exp(y_true-y_pred)))))
```

Then:

```
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer=sgd,metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Sure, unnecessarily complex with additional log calculations. Citing: `Almost the three times more costly, for a 0 incorrectly predicted as 1` - why would you want `almost` when you can easily get `exactly` (or any other weighting he desires)? First code sometimes uses `numpy` (e.g. `log`), sometimes uses Python's standard `abs` and other times `exp` incorrectly (there is `math.exp`, not `exp`). Furthermore it uses `ŷ`; all in all strange mix of math and programming, pretty unreadable IMO. Those are the major flaws I see in your answer.

Comment: Furthermore, as the premise of this answer is in my opinion incorrect (applying `log` transforms instead of simply using weighting provided by `Tensorflow`), one cannot fix it simply (if you could do that I would leave comment with my opinion instead). Minor flaws: second code (with `keras.backend`) mixes even more libraries (`keras`, `standard`, `math` [implicitly], `numpy`). No example is definitely the smallest flaw. If those were the only ones I would only leave this comment, as it currently stands I think it might influence OP (and his code) badly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In fact I see beyond your comments regarding mixed libraries and complexity. Critical thinking while coding is my biggest learning from your explanation.